# Not possible to open Android Studio in Android studio with Flutter after AndroidStudio update

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I updated my Android studio to Hedgehog version (2023.1.1). Since that I am not able to Open the "Editing in Android Studio" in Flutter to create a signed App bundle.
I already deleted Android studio and installed Giraffe version but none of it is working. Previously I had Tiramisu version which worked. I also created a new app but it doesn't differ to other apps.
I always get following error: [image: IDE error occured]

Here is the way I try to open it and how it was working before.

[image: Go to Flutter -> Open for Editing in Android Studio]

The error message report is below.
I have no Idea what to do if even deleting and reinstalling to other versions is not working.

Error report:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: configureNewProject should be used with new projects only
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.importing.GradleProjectImporter$Companion.configureNewProject(GradleProjectImporter.kt:203)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.importing.GradleProjectImporter$importAndOpenProjectCore$1$1$1.invokeSuspend(GradleProjectImporter.kt:98)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.DispatchedRunnable.run(DispatchedRunnable.kt:35)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:209)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$100(TransactionGuardImpl.java:21)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$1.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:191)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:829)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$3.run(ApplicationImpl.java:454)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:79)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:122)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:41)
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:789)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:740)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:734)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:759)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:667)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent$lambda$7(IdeEventQueue.kt:571)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.withoutImplicitRead(ApplicationImpl.java:1444)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:571)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.access$_dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:68)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:349)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:348)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:787)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:348)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:343)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity$lambda$1(IdeEventQueue.kt:995)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:113)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.kt:995)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent$lambda$4(IdeEventQueue.kt:343)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:829)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:385)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.PlatformTaskSupportKt.pumpEventsForHierarchy(PlatformTaskSupport.kt:341)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.PlatformTaskSupportKt.access$pumpEventsForHierarchy(PlatformTaskSupport.kt:1)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.PlatformTaskSupport$runBlockingModalInternal$2$1.invoke(PlatformTaskSupport.kt:139)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.PlatformTaskSupport$runBlockingModalInternal$2$1.invoke(PlatformTaskSupport.kt:121)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ModalityKt.inModalContext(modality.kt:36)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.PlatformTaskSupport.runBlockingModalInternal(PlatformTaskSupport.kt:121)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.PlatformTaskSupport.access$runBlockingModalInternal(PlatformTaskSupport.kt:41)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.PlatformTaskSupport$runBlockingModalInternal$1.invoke(PlatformTaskSupport.kt:113)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.PlatformTaskSupport$runBlockingModalInternal$1.invoke(PlatformTaskSupport.kt:110)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.CancellationKt$ensureCurrentJob$1.invoke(cancellation.kt:68)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.CancellationKt.withCurrentJob$lambda$0(cancellation.kt:17)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.Cancellation.withCurrentJob(Cancellation.java:60)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.CancellationKt.withCurrentJob(cancellation.kt:17)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.CancellationKt.executeWithJobAndCompleteIt(cancellation.kt:126)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.CancellationKt.ensureCurrentJob(cancellation.kt:67)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.CancellationKt.ensureCurrentJobAllowingOrphan(cancellation.kt:51)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.PlatformTaskSupport.runBlockingModalInternal(PlatformTaskSupport.kt:110)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.TasksKt.runBlockingModalWithRawProgressReporter(tasks.kt:263)
at com.intellij.ide.impl.ProjectUtilKt.runBlockingUnderModalProgress(ProjectUtil.kt:731)
at com.intellij.ide.impl.ProjectUtilKt.runBlockingUnderModalProgress$default(ProjectUtil.kt:726)
at com.intellij.ide.impl.ProjectUtilKt.runUnderModalProgressIfIsEdt(ProjectUtil.kt:718)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.openProject(ProjectManagerImpl.kt:523)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.importing.GradleProjectImporter.importAndOpenProjectCore(GradleProjectImporter.kt:89)
at io.flutter.actions.OpenAndroidModule.openOrImportProject(OpenAndroidModule.java:64)
at io.flutter.actions.OpenAndroidModule.actionPerformed(OpenAndroidModule.java:52)
at io.flutter.actions.OpenInAndroidStudioAction.actionPerformed(OpenInAndroidStudioAction.java:60)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.doPerformActionOrShowPopup(ActionUtil.java:333)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.lambda$performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks$4(ActionUtil.java:307)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:356)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:307)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$performAction$5(ActionMenuItem.java:299)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:225)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.performAction(ActionMenuItem.java:292)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$new$0(ActionMenuItem.java:67)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$4(ActionMenuItem.java:114)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:105)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performUserActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:94)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:114)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:526)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:558)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6657)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3385)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6422)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5027)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4855)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4954)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4581)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4522)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2808)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4855)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:791)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:740)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:734)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:764)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:762)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:761)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:667)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:615)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:570)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.access$_dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:68)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:349)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:348)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:787)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:348)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:343)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity$lambda$1(IdeEventQueue.kt:995)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:113)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.kt:995)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent$lambda$4(IdeEventQueue.kt:343)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:829)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:385)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)

Comment: Tiramisu is version of android not of android studio. Please do this with android studio -> file -> Invalidate cashes and restart and check again

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't change anything :(
I still get the IDE error message and Android Studio is instantly closing.